# QSlider increase handle size

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets, qslider

How do I increase the height of this slider's handle:

[image: I have slider like this]

As shown here:

[image: explanation image]

Is subclassing QAbstractSlider the only way?

Here is the stylesheet from my code:

```css
QSlider::groove:horizontal {
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    height: 32px; /* the groove expands to the size of the slider by default. by giving it a height, it has a fixed size */
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, 
        stop:0 #B1B1B1, stop:1 #c4c4c4);
    margin: 2px 0; 
}
QSlider::handle:horizontal {
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, 
        stop:0 #b4b4b4, stop:1 #8f8f8f);
    border: 1px solid #5c5c5c;
    width: 40px;
    margin: -20px 0; /* handle is placed by default on the contents rect of the groove. Expand outside the groove */
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this stylesheet:

```
.QSlider {
    min-height: 68px;
    max-height: 68px;
    background: #5F4141;
}

.QSlider::groove:horizontal {
    border: 1px solid #262626;
    height: 5px;
    background: #393939;
    margin: 0 12px;
}

.QSlider::handle:horizontal {
    background: #22B14C;
    border: 5px solid #B5E61D;
    width: 23px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: -24px -12px;
}
```

It will produce the following:

[image]

Please note the the height of the slider is made constant by setting both `min-height` and `max-height` to the same value.

Answer (score 2):

I copied your exact code into a form in Qt Designer. The slider handle looks large enough.

However, when adding a layout, the whole slider's size isn't large enough to show the complete handle. I simply added this:

```
QSlider {
    height: 80px;
}
```

And get this result:

[image: Form Slider Screenshot]

Comment: ye, but i dont need to increase the progressline height, thats the point